# Wordpress doesn't respect "ver" parameter in styles

Tags: css

My Wordpress server prints the enqueued styles without version parameter, making them cached forever. My local installation prints the styles as they should look, with "ver" intact. Does not matter if the styles are in parent or child theme.

Comment: disable plugins and switch themes until you find the cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the "disable all plugins and turn them on one by one" helped. It was "SmartPayCard" plugin.

Comment: You can accept your own answer as the right one